# Objective C - UIApplicationMain(nil, nil, nil, nil); error

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a project and I have some ready-to-use functions. It asked me to change those but when I am trying to change it , it doesnt allow me to compile the program. The thing is ;

I have (viewDidLoad) function and have this line on that function

```
[self.view insertSubview:mainViewController.view belowSubview:infoButton];
```

I want to remove the infoButton of itself, I can remove easily but when I try to modify my return value which is ;

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(nil, nil, nil, nil);
```

It doesnt allow me to compile program. What should I change actually? Sincerely yours.

The thing that I will remove is ;

```
IBOutlet UIButton *infoButton;  //In my .h file
[self.view insertSubview:mainViewController.view belowSubview:infoButton]; //In my .m file
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(nil, nil, nil, nil); //in my main.m file
```

Here is the original version of my main.m fie ;

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(nil, nil, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
}
```

Cant answer since I got no rep points. Here is the answer =>

Alright. When I try to remove

```
IBOutlet UIButton *infoButton;  //remove
```

and modify 
    [self.view insertSubview:mainViewController.view belowSubview:infoButton];

like

```
[self.view insertSubview:mainViewController.view belowSubview:nil];
```

it gives me

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT". 
Passing Argument 1 of 'UIApplicationMain' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Answer (score 1):

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(nil, nil, nil, nil);
```

should be

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Alright. When I try to remove

    IBOutlet UIButton *infoButton;  //Silinecek

and modify [self.view insertSubview:mainViewController.view belowSubview:infoButton];

like

[self.view insertSubview:mainViewController.view belowSubview:nil];


it gives me 

 int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT". 
Passing Argument 1 of 'UIApplicationMain' makes integer from pointer without a cast